# Best method for Parallel Loop C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a function that that will be executed many times and it takes around 2 minutes to execute.I'm not sure about the exact number but it's expected to be around 250.000 times. That's why I need use parallel to make it faster.

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
     ConcurrentBag<object> list = new ConcurrentBag<object>();
     int count = 0;
     int i     = 0;

     while (count < 10)
     {
         if (myFunction(i, list)) count = 0;
         else count++;
         i++;
     }
}

private static bool myFunction(int number, ConcurrentBag<object> list)
{
    // My code (it takes around 2 minutes here), it could return false here

    list.Add(new object());
    return true;
}
```

Basically I'm searching for something using an API, I'm searching using an incremental IdNumber, but I noticed that sometimes it skips a number. I want to get all the data in the API so I need to search all possible IDs.
The API is paid by request so I can't make too many unnecessary requests by using a ParallelFor loop with a big number. The function return false when the Id searched is not found.

My plan is to keep making request by increasing the number searched. If it fails to get 10 id numbers in a row, it means i already got everything and should stop. I cant stop in the first failure because of the skipped numbers that happens sometimes.

As you can see, the loop will run until my function returns false 10 times in a row. `ParallelForEach` and `ParallelFor` which I usually use are not suited for this. Whats the best way to make this with threads?

this is what I came up with:

```
    ConcurrentBag<Person> list = new ConcurrentBag<Person>();
    int i = 1;
    while(i < 250000)
    {
        List<Task<bool>> tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            int id = i;
            tasks.Add(Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return myFunction(id,list);
             }));
            i++;
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        bool shouldContinue = false;
        foreach (Task<bool> t in tasks)
        {
            if (t.Result) shouldContinue = true;
        }

        if (shouldContinue) continue;
        else break;
    }
```

Comment: Why does it take so long?  Is this calling a database?  A file?  Is it doing large calculations?  We need more info

Comment: If you're expecting to run something that takes 2mins 250000 times in a reasonable run time, this implies that your workload in `myFunction` is in a paused, sleeping/waiting state for a considerable amount of time and is not CPU-bound (otherwise how could this possibly complete in a reasonable amount of time). This leads to the question: What exactly is `// My code` doing?

Comment: Define "in a row" when you run your function invocations in parallel.

Comment: Its making HttpRequests , around 2 or 3 of them but one of them takes around 40 seconds

Comment: @kadzu use async await then, not parallel

Comment: `ParallelFor` etc. are only convenient wrappers around "classic" multithreading, so why do you rule them out as "not suited"? it sounds like a good idea to do many fast requests while one slow request processes, but you need to carefully plan the total number of concurrent requests and be aware that you're putting more load on the server too, which will result in slower response times overall.

Comment: Threading should be used in CPU-bound situation, not I/O-bound situations. Using async/await, you can wait for an I/O-bound process to complete and do other useful work on the same thread while waiting.

Comment: Basically I'm searching for something using an API, I'm searching using an incremental IdNumber, but I noticed that sometimes it skips a number. I want to get all the data in the API so I need to search all possible IDs.

Comment: Time for my monthly recommendation. [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) offers all the tools you need for this complex async/rate-limiting question.

Comment: The API is paid by request so I can't make too many unnecessary requests by using a ParallelFor loop with a big number. The function return false when the Id searched is not found.

Comment: My plan is to keep making request by increasing the number searched. If it fails to get 10 id numbers in a row, it means i already got everything and should stop. I cant stop in the first failure because of the skipped numbers that happens sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

> ParallelForEach and ParallelFor which I usually use are not suited for
>   this

Why? if you are running in spaces of 10, then it is suited, if you were trying to stop as soon as the first result it is not as expected, then the process can not be parallel.

Try with linq and `AsParallel`:

```
public static class DemoClass
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentBag<object> ListTrue = new ConcurrentBag<object>();
    private static readonly ConcurrentBag<int> ListFalse = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sequence = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList(); //Prepare a sequence from 1 to 10

        sequence
            .AsParallel()
            .ForAll(i => //i will take the value of each element of the sequence
            {
                //If your function returns true nothing happend here, the element where
                //added in "myFunction", if the method returned false, then just save
                //the value so you can check the results outside this parallel for
                if (!myFunction(i, ListTrue))
                    ListFalse.Add(i);
            });

        System.Console.WriteLine(
            $@"{ListFalse.Count} elements resulted false, {ListTrue.Count} where true"
        );
    }

    private static bool myFunction(int number, ConcurrentBag<object> list)
    {
        // My code (it takes around 2 minutes here), it could return false here

        list.Add(new object());
        return true;
    }
}
```

As the comments already said, you need to be careful, if this process involves waiting for things like services will work, if the operation is bound to the processor this will generate unnecessary overhead

> the loop will run until my function returns false 10 times in a row

Then the code cannot run in parallel, since you need the previous responses to decide, you can use async and await to have a better resources usage, but the process for each client will be serial and not parallel.

Or you can take the parallel and execute in batches of ten, that latter you can analyze in any way you want.